# setState when receive props from parent component which fetch async data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have `componentA` which as act as the container, which call to api, I want to pass the data to a form which is a component

`<form data={res.body.data} />`

so in form when I can setState? because `form` has it own state. Can't do it within constructor of form component because it's async data.

Comment: Do you have code example?

Comment: Pass the state data as a prop into form.

Comment: response changes container state -> container state is passed to form as prop -> form is rendered only after request has finished

Comment: There are number of solutions depending on your architecture. Simplest pass prop into Form component when request is done. Then you could use state management layer like redux, and map data in mapToState. You could even pass entire promise as a prop and render data once its resolved.

Comment: As pointed out by Chris, make your api call in componentA's componentDidMount()  hook and then pass the data as prop to form component

Answer (score 0):

You can wait to render the form component until the API component has fetched the data. That way you ensure you always have data.

**API**

```
fetch() {
  (...) // Do the fetch and setState
  this.setState({ data: res.body.data });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.data ? <form data={this.state.data} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your limited code, I suppose your would need to checkout  [componentWillReceiveProps(object nextProps)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops). You can check the async data passed from data as component `Form`'s prop in the hook, like `if (!!nextProps.data) { ... // data is ready}`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. You need to use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

```
class Form extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    /* make your verifications or whatever */
    this.setState(/* your new state */);
  }

  render() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: how to I pass back the state back to the parent? the form has no submit button, I have to tie a function to onChange?

Comment: @XieXieFang It's up to you. For example you can pass a function to Form as a prop from the parent and when you want call it from Form and the parent will know of it. like <Form data={data} handleChange={parenteFunctionHere} />

Answer (score -1):

In Redux Form:

You can load the data by setting initialValues in the state.

Once data is received, you can store the data in reducer, and then connect the initalValues with that reducer.

Refer to this link for reference:
https://redux-form.com/7.2.1/examples/initializefromstate/

Comment: Redux is not mentioned in the question at all, so I have no reason to see why this answer is relevant.

Comment: This answer treats the actual question as irrelevant.